# Can you solve a matrix with just one row?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Can you solve a matrix with just one row?
For example, something like $[4, 1,  5, 1 | 7]$

Comment: As in an augmented matrix as described [in Wikipedia here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Row_reduction)? That would just mean there's one linear equation of four variables, and the solution would have 3 free variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, and in fact, there are infinitely many solutions.

The system you have is equivalent to finding $a,b,c,d$ s.t.
$$4a + b + 5c + d = 7.$$
$(a,b,c,d) = (7/4,0,0,0)$ will solve the equation above, as will $(0,7,0,0), (0,0,7/5,0)$ or $(0,0,0,7)$.

If you express
$$a=\frac{7-b-5c-d}{4}$$
then by picking any values of $b,c,d$, you can always construct $a$ s.t. $4a + b + 5c + d = 7$ holds true using the formula above. Since $b,c,d$ can be arbitrary, we call them "free variables". There are 3 of these free variables, so we say that the solution space is of dimension 3.

Comment: One could also write $b$ in terms of $a,c,$ and $d$; $c$ in terms of $a,b,$ and $d$; or $d$ in terms of $a,b,$ and $c$, so the free variables could just as well be $a,c,$ and $d$; $a,b,$ and $d$; or $a,b,$ and $c$.

Comment: So I guess the solution should be **x = [7/4 0 0 0] -b[1/4 0 0 0] -c[5/4 0 0 0] -d[1/4 0 0 0]** also **x = [0 7 0 0] -a[0 4 0 0] -c[0 5 0 0] -d[0 1 0 0]** and so on ?

Comment: Look at it this way $$
\begin{cases}
    \begin{array}{ccccc}
        a = & \frac{7}{4} & -b \frac{1}{4} & -c\frac{5}{4} & -d \frac{1}{4} \\
        b = &  & b &  &  \\
        c = &  &  & c &  \\
        d = &  &  &  & d 
    \end{array}
\end{cases}$$
The solution is
$$\textbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix}
    a \\ b \\ c \\ d
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
    7/4 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix} + b \begin{bmatrix}
    -1/4 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 
\end{bmatrix} + c \begin{bmatrix}
    -5/4 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 
\end{bmatrix} + d \begin{bmatrix}
    -1/4 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: You can check that this $\textbf{x}$ with any values of $b,c,d$ will solve the original equation. One can also say that the solution $\textbf{x}$ is in the _translated_ space spanned by the vectors corresponding to $a,b,c$ above. In other words, for any
$$\textbf{y} \in \text{span} \left\{\begin{bmatrix}
    -1/4 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
    -5/4 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
    -1/4 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix} \right\}, \qquad \textbf{x} = \textbf{y} + \begin{bmatrix}
    7/4 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix} \text{ is a solution.}$$

Comment: Also, as Geoffrey pointed out, you can express any of the $a,b,c,d$ in terms of the other three variables and get a different (but equivalent) representation of the solution and the translated space.